# SQL Query with AVG/Datediff/CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, average, datediff

```
SELECT
    AVG(
        DATEDIFF(
            day,
            P.[ProjectCreatedDate],
            CASE WHEN T.[Reported Milestones] LIKE '02 Request Assigned' THEN T.[TaskActualFinishDate]
        )
    ) AS AverageAssignmentAge
```

I have the above query where i'm trying to find the average day of assignment between created date and request assigned date. It doesn't work, how can I fix this?

Comment: Use `end` after case statement.

Comment: Please post the rest of your query and some sample data, and please explain how it isn't working. Are you getting an error message or just incorrect results? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tip: If you have a complicated `SELECT` clause it might be worthwhile using a subquery to logically separate intermediate results to make it more readable. It is unfortunate that SQL still does not allow for iterative steps and temporary variables in `SELECT`.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai - I've used END after my CASE statement but the query didn't yield any results either.

Comment: @Dai i get syntax errors, no results. I'm using Microsofy SQL Server management Studio.

Comment: @SeeCindyWalk Please post your **entire query** and sample data. We don't have enough to go on.

Comment: @SeeCindyWalk Then add `SQL Server` tag to the question.  `SQL` is just a language.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the datediff function inside the case expression, and then contain that whole case expression within the aggregate function.

```
SELECT
      AVG( CASE WHEN T.[Reported Milestones] LIKE '02 Request Assigned' THEN 
                  DATEDIFF(DAY,P.[ProjectCreatedDate],T.[TaskActualFinishDate])
           END)
      AS averageassignmentage
```

**NOTE** when dealing with task "duration" an "end date" is typically referring to the "end of that day", but what is recorded in the db equates to the "beginning of that day". So you almost certainly want to add one to the datediff calculation which is counting the number of days from beginning of the start date to beginning of the end date.

test/example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88442/1)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Reported Milestones] varchar(19), [ProjectCreatedDate] datetime, [TaskActualFinishDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Reported Milestones], [ProjectCreatedDate], [TaskActualFinishDate])
VALUES
    ('02 Request Assigned', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-10 00:00:00'),
    ('02 Request Assigned', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-10 00:00:00'),
    ('02 Request Assigned', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-10 00:00:00'),
    ('xxx', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', NULL),
    ('xxx', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', NULL)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      AVG( CASE WHEN [Reported Milestones] LIKE '02 Request Assigned' THEN 
                  DATEDIFF(DAY,[ProjectCreatedDate],[TaskActualFinishDate])+1
           END)
      AS averageassignmentage
    , COUNT( CASE WHEN [Reported Milestones] LIKE '02 Request Assigned' THEN 
                  TaskActualFinishDate
           END)
      AS sample_size
from table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88442/1/0)**:

```
| averageassignmentage | sample_size |
|----------------------|-------------|
|                   10 |           3 |
```